# PCP Design - HX711 ADC not stable

Tags: pcb, adc, layout, drift

I have designed a board with a HX711 for a kitchen scale (MCU on the board is an esp32-s3-wroom-1u-n8r8). When I start the system, the HX711 starts at a random value and drifts over some time (seconds to 1-2 minutes) until it is stable.

On the attached picture you can see the layout (without gnd-planes) and the schematic. The circuit diagram is basically the same as in the HX711 data sheet.

[image: Schematic]

[image: Layout]

[image: PCB]

Everything is supplied with 3.3V and the board has four layers:

1. signals + GND
2. GND
3. +3.3V
4. signals + GND

I soldered 4 load cells to the pads under the HX711 so that together they form a full bridge.

As mentioned before, when I start the system, the HX711 starts at a random value and drifts over some time (seconds to a few minutes) until it is stable.
This happens every time I power up the PCB. It does now happen, when I only flash new frimware on the PCB, so the power supply is not "restarted".

I can observe the same behaviour both with and without soldered load cells.

I suspect that there are some capacitive effects that are interfering with the HX711, but so far I have not been able to find out the source of this. And I am not even sure if that is really the problem.

Did anyone had the same problem?
Do you have any ideas what I can try or see some no-go's on my layout?
And also would you recommend to use the HX711 for a series production?

Answer (score 0):

1. Your selected excitation voltage has very little margin for tolerances and headroom for the regulator (175mV drop *nominal*). There is no specified tolerance for Vbg, so I would definitely allow more voltage, maybe 800mV. Also, some kinds of regulator circuit exhibit small instabilities with very low voltage drop.
2. Is it possible you've mixed up capacitor values or put 10uF caps where 100nF are in the schematic? That could cause oscillation, which could result in symptoms such as what you are seeing.

Comment: Thanks, for your suggestions.
1. I get the same problems with a 5V supply. The DS says that the Vout of the LDO needs to be 100mV below Vsup, so at least with 5V there should be more than enough headroom...

2. Actually only C4 in my schematic is in the DS a 0.1 uF capacitor. But somewhere I read that this could be a little bit to small and a 10 uF should be used. I will give it a try and replace C4 with 0.1 uF caps. But I do not really understand why this should help, since this is only the differential lowpass and with 10 uF or 0.1 uF I only move the cut-off frequency ot am I wrong?

Comment: A capacitor with the wrong characteristics at Vbg - C2-  (too low capacitance, too high capacitance, ESR out of expected range) could cause oscillation since it's part of a control loop. More is not always better.

Comment: I agree with that. C2 is 0.1 uF and is exactly as in the hx711 datasheet. I will have a closer look on Vbg and the control loop.

Comment: @JonathanO. I ask partly because they look very similar in the photo, but it's probably possible to distinguish the two types by looking at them directly (or through a microscope).